# Compare timestamps in subsequent records with pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large data set of 30000 KB (saved as a "pandas" dataFrame) of chat conversations between experts and users.

Each row represents a message sent by either the expert or the user. I want to measure the time between the second message the user sent and the second response of the expert.

(notice that sometimes an expert and a user type and send a group of consecutive messages that should be addressed as one big message and also notice that sometimes some of the data is missing, for instance - message 0 in sessionId 111)

for example: in sessionId 222, I want to measure the time between index 3 and index 4 (in this case 22 minutes)

[image: Data Sample]

here is the data presented as a list:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = [[222.0, 0.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 20:12'],
 [222.0, 1.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 20:41'],
 [222.0, 2.0, 'expert', '12/6/2017 21:15'],
 [222.0, 3.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 21:45'],
 [222.0, 4.0, 'expert', '12/6/2017 22:07'],
 [222.0, 5.0, 'expert', '12/6/2017 23:36'],
 [443.0, 0.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 20:41'],
 [443.0, 1.0, 'expert', '12/6/2017 21:15'],
 [443.0, 2.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 21:45'],
 [111.0, 1.0, 'expert', '12/6/2017 21:45'],
 [111.0, 2.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 22:07'],
 [243.0, 0.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 20:12'],
 [243.0, 1.0, 'expert', '12/6/2017 20:41'],
 [243.0, 2.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 21:15'],
 [243.0, 3.0, 'expert', '12/6/2017 21:45'],
 [243.0, 4.0, 'user', '12/6/2017 22:07'],
 [243.0, 5.0, 'expert', '12/6/2017 23:36'],
 [243.0, 6.0, 'user', '12/7/2017 0:05'],
 [243.0, 7.0, 'user', '12/7/2017 0:58'],
 [243.0, 8.0, 'user', '12/7/2017 0:58']]
```

What I tried:

a. use pd.groupby "sessionId" and "interaction"

b. create a new column of the userType shifted downwards by 1 row

c. compare the original userType with the shifted userType and find mismatches

d. in each third mismatch - find the time between the mismatched message and the previous message (interaction).

Can you please show me working examples of this method or possibly other methods?

Comment: Does my answer satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the timestamps if not already done

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)

#Order by session and time before taking differences.
df.sort_values('sessionId','timestamp', inplace = True)

df['delta_time'] = df.groupby('sessionId').timestamp.diff()
```

Result:

```
    sessionId   interaction userType    timestamp   delta_time
9   111.0   1.0 expert  2017-12-06 21:45:00 
10  111.0   2.0 user    2017-12-06 22:07:00 0 days 00:22:00.000000000
0   222.0   0.0 user    2017-12-06 20:12:00 
1   222.0   1.0 user    2017-12-06 20:41:00 0 days 00:29:00.000000000
2   222.0   2.0 expert  2017-12-06 21:15:00 0 days 00:34:00.000000000
3   222.0   3.0 user    2017-12-06 21:45:00 0 days 00:30:00.000000000
4   222.0   4.0 expert  2017-12-06 22:07:00 0 days 00:22:00.000000000
5   222.0   5.0 expert  2017-12-06 23:36:00 0 days 01:29:00.000000000
11  243.0   0.0 user    2017-12-06 20:12:00 
12  243.0   1.0 expert  2017-12-06 20:41:00 0 days 00:29:00.000000000
13  243.0   2.0 user    2017-12-06 21:15:00 0 days 00:34:00.000000000
14  243.0   3.0 expert  2017-12-06 21:45:00 0 days 00:30:00.000000000
15  243.0   4.0 user    2017-12-06 22:07:00 0 days 00:22:00.000000000
16  243.0   5.0 expert  2017-12-06 23:36:00 0 days 01:29:00.000000000
17  243.0   6.0 user    2017-12-07 00:05:00 0 days 00:29:00.000000000
18  243.0   7.0 user    2017-12-07 00:58:00 0 days 00:53:00.000000000
19  243.0   8.0 user    2017-12-07 00:58:00 0 days 00:00:00.000000000
6   443.0   0.0 user    2017-12-06 20:41:00 
7   443.0   1.0 expert  2017-12-06 21:15:00 0 days 00:34:00.000000000
8   443.0   2.0 user    2017-12-06 21:45:00 0 days 00:30:00.000000000
```

Another way would be to create a new column for the next message, as follows:

```
df['nextMessage'] = df.groupby('sessionId').timestamp.shift(-1)
df['deltaTime'] = df.nextMessage- df.timestamp
```

Result

```
sessionId   interaction,    userType    timestamp   nextMessage deltaTime
9   111.0   1.0 expert  2017-12-06 21:45:00 2017-12-06 22:07:00 0 days 00:22:00.000000000
10  111.0   2.0 user    2017-12-06 22:07:00     
0   222.0   0.0 user    2017-12-06 20:12:00 2017-12-06 20:41:00 0 days 00:29:00.000000000
1   222.0   1.0 user    2017-12-06 20:41:00 2017-12-06 21:15:00 0 days 00:34:00.000000000
2   222.0   2.0 expert  2017-12-06 21:15:00 2017-12-06 21:45:00 0 days 00:30:00.000000000
3   222.0   3.0 user    2017-12-06 21:45:00 2017-12-06 22:07:00 0 days 00:22:00.000000000
4   222.0   4.0 expert  2017-12-06 22:07:00 2017-12-06 23:36:00 0 days 01:29:00.000000000
5   222.0   5.0 expert  2017-12-06 23:36:00     
11  243.0   0.0 user    2017-12-06 20:12:00 2017-12-06 20:41:00 0 days 00:29:00.000000000
12  243.0   1.0 expert  2017-12-06 20:41:00 2017-12-06 21:15:00 0 days 00:34:00.000000000
13  243.0   2.0 user    2017-12-06 21:15:00 2017-12-06 21:45:00 0 days 00:30:00.000000000
14  243.0   3.0 expert  2017-12-06 21:45:00 2017-12-06 22:07:00 0 days 00:22:00.000000000
15  243.0   4.0 user    2017-12-06 22:07:00 2017-12-06 23:36:00 0 days 01:29:00.000000000
16  243.0   5.0 expert  2017-12-06 23:36:00 2017-12-07 00:05:00 0 days 00:29:00.000000000
17  243.0   6.0 user    2017-12-07 00:05:00 2017-12-07 00:58:00 0 days 00:53:00.000000000
18  243.0   7.0 user    2017-12-07 00:58:00 2017-12-07 00:58:00 0 days 00:00:00.000000000
19  243.0   8.0 user    2017-12-07 00:58:00     
6   443.0   0.0 user    2017-12-06 20:41:00 2017-12-06 21:15:00 0 days 00:34:00.000000000
7   443.0   1.0 expert  2017-12-06 21:15:00 2017-12-06 21:45:00 0 days 00:30:00.000000000
8   443.0   2.0 user    2017-12-06 21:45:00
```

Comment: This is definitely in the right direction - thanks
I'm not sure though how to only pick the delta time between the second message of the user and the third message of the expert (given they consist of a changing amount of rows) without iterating through this list row-by-row (which I am trying to avoid as it's a really long process that takes several minutes).

Comment: Ok, so the delta should only reflect the difference between expert/user interaction?  For instance, the difference between the users first message and the expert's response?

Comment: I want to measure the time between the second message the user sent and the second response of the expert.
message = 1 or more consecutive messages sent by either the expert or the user.

for example: in sessionId 222, I want to measure the time between index 3 and index 4 (in this case 22 minutes)

Comment: @Sharonio Can you give me more examples?  You want the time between index 3 and index 4.  Do you also want the time between 13 and 14?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for